# Stringr pattern look around: R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to extract substrings when it matches certain pattern. For example:

```r
str <- "For each of the following statements, please indicate how true it is for\r\nyou with respect to your interaction with the puzzles in the game. - This is the part of string I want to extract."
str_extract(str, pattern = "(?<=-)\\w+") #Output = This
```

How do I get the whole string?

Comment: Do you want `str_extract(str, pattern = "(?<=-\\s).*")#
[1] "This is the part of string I want to extract."` `\\w+` extracts the first word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to extract the whole sentence till the `.`, match for one or more characters that are not a `.` (`[^.]+`) followed by the `.` (`\\.` - escape as it is metacharacter that matches any character) after the regex lookaround to match the `-` and a space (`\\s`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str, pattern = "(?<=-\\s)[^.]+\\.")
[1] "This is the part of string I want to extract."
```